# Four Panel in Frame with Different Layout

Tags: java, layout, panels

I am trying to design an interface with 4 different panels in 1 single frame. I have included 2 of the panel descriptions in the code I included below.

Below is part of my code:

```
public class finalFrame extends JFrame {
       PanelA a = new PanelA()
       PanelB b = new PanelB()
       // ...
      public finalFrame() {
          super();
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          //...
          //...
          //...
          add(a);
          add(b);
          } 
}
class PanelA extends JPanel {
      JButton bt = new JButton();
      add(bt);
     //...
  }

class PanelB extends JPanel {
// ...
//... }

class Program {
      public static void main(String [] args) {
            finalFrame fr = new finalFrame();
      }
 }
```

This code doesn't seem to work (it only displays the last panel at an odd size (Not what I wanted)). Yet, when I set up the different panels WITHIN the frame class (and not individual panel classes), it works perfectly. Why can't I use different panel classes and then just add them all to the final Frame class afterwards?

Furthermore (sorry for all the questions), if I include the panel set up within the frame class and include a frame layout, then it works (as I just mentioned). However, if I include the panel set up within the frame class but I DON'T include a frame layout, then it only displays the last panel using the frame layout. Why isn't it portraying any of the other panels??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Frames` in Java have `BorderLayout` as its `LayoutManager`.

So to add any `panel` to `Frame`, you can do like following:

```
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

These values work and are valid.
If you use 4 different locations from above for your four different panels while adding them to your frame, then your panels will be visible.

Here's a demonstration to add four panels using `GridLayout`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridFrame extends JFrame
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public GridFrame()
  {
    super("Grid Demo");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    add(new PanelA());
    add(new PanelB());
    add(new PanelC());
    add(new PanelD());

    setSize(500, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Call Swing stuff like this, since Swing is not thread safe.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        new GridFrame();
      }
    });
  }
}

class PanelA extends JPanel
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public PanelA()
  {
    setBackground(Color.RED);
  }
}

class PanelB extends JPanel
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public PanelB()
  {
    setBackground(Color.BLUE);
  }
}

class PanelC extends JPanel
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public PanelC()
  {
    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
  }
}

class PanelD extends JPanel
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public PanelD()
  {
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
  }
}
```

Comment: By Default ther border of `JFrame` is `FlowLayout` . isn't it?

Comment: Border of `JFrame` as `FlowLayout`? By default `JFrame`'s `LayoutManager` is `BorderLayout`. The documentation says: _The default content pane will have a BorderLayout manager set on it._ and since `add()` method in `JFrame` now directly adds `components` to its `content pane`, it works. Its not `FlowLayout`.

Comment: why is it only showing the last panel that I add though? Does this have to do with the default frame layout?

Comment: If its your code that you're talking about, then yes. When you do `add(a);`, the frame adds the component `a` in `center`, then when you do `add(b);`, the frame adds the component in center again, effectively covering the previously added components. Use Layout hints as I showed above in my code, and you can then easily resolve the issue.

Comment: @vmck: You can check out the demo code in my updated answer for further insights. :)

Comment: @AwfullyAwesome wow that clears so much up thanks! I thought the default layout for frames was GridLayout. But thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first make your Frame That contain at least four `JPanel` in your case. Use `GridLayout` explore some, than make each Panel individually and add in `JFrame`
something like this:

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
frame.add(new Panel2().getPanel());
frame.add(new Panel2().getPanel());
frame.add(new Panel3().getPanel());
frame.add(new Panel4().getPanel());
frame.setSize(100,100);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: No need to do `getPanel()` if `Panel2`, `Panel3` and so on are `JPanel`s.

Comment: is `new Panel2()` is constructor means no return type, `getPanel()` is the method which return the `JPanel`.. . are we cool? @AwfullyAwesome

Comment: Well I was saying in the context of constructors only. If `Panel2()` is the `constructor`, you need not add the `getPanel()` method. Check it out on an IDE to see, if you don't believe me. :)

Comment: `Container.add(String,Component) is not applicable argument mismatch` for `this.add( new Panel(),BorderLayout.NORTH);` where no error for `this.add( new Panel().getPanel(),BorderLayout.NORTH);` Please can you show any example

Comment: I get it that is why i also Vote up for you, and in older version of JDK 4 or 5 JFrame Default Layout was FlowLayout studied back in college i remember that :):)

Comment: Wow.. :D The earliest of JDK's I started with was version 1.4. I started my Swing stuff from JDK 6 I guess, so don't know if it was FlowLayout for JFrame. JPanels have FlowLayout as default still though. :)